# how to merge some same keys from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I getting this array as a result for mysql query. I want to remove the duplicate hotel_id hotel_name from the array but keeping other data.

```
array(6) {
    [0] => array(17) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "1" ["hotel_id"] => string(1) "1" ["name"] => string(31) "Vilamendhoo Island Resort & Spa" ["city"] => string(11) "Vilamendhoo" ["country"] => string(8) "Maldives" ["image"] => string(6) "01.jpg" ["address"] => string(0) "" ["wifi"] => string(1) "1" ["atoll"] => string(14) "South Ari Atol" ["type"] => string(6) "Resort" ["stars"] => string(1) "4" ["room_id"] => string(1) "1" ["room_type"] => string(29) "Garden view room - full board" ["description"] => string(47) "Limited Time Offer. Rate includes 20% discount!" ["availability"] => string(12) "only 4 rooms" ["rates"] => string(2) "25" ["breakfast"] => string(1) "1"
    } [1] => array(17) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "2" ["hotel_id"] => string(1) "1" ["name"] => string(31) "Vilamendhoo Island Resort & Spa" ["city"] => string(11) "Vilamendhoo" ["country"] => string(8) "Maldives" ["image"] => string(6) "01.jpg" ["address"] => string(0) "" ["wifi"] => string(1) "1" ["atoll"] => string(14) "South Ari Atol" ["type"] => string(6) "Resort" ["stars"] => string(1) "4" ["room_id"] => string(1) "2" ["room_type"] => string(24) "Beach villa - full board" ["description"] => string(47) "Limited Time Offer. Rate includes 20% discount!" ["availability"] => string(9) "Available" ["rates"] => string(2) "50" ["breakfast"] => string(1) "1"
    } [2] => array(17) {
        ["id"] => NULL ["hotel_id"] => NULL ["name"] => string(28) "Kuredu Island Resort and Spa" ["city"] => string(9) "Kuredhdhu" ["country"] => string(8) "Maldives" ["image"] => string(14) "12137_Main.jpg" ["address"] => string(0) "" ["wifi"] => NULL ["atoll"] => string(15) "Lhaviyani Atoll" ["type"] => string(6) "Resort" ["stars"] => string(1) "4" ["room_id"] => NULL ["room_type"] => NULL ["description"] => NULL ["availability"] => NULL ["rates"] => NULL ["breakfast"] => NULL
    } [3] => array(17) {
        ["id"] => NULL ["hotel_id"] => NULL ["name"] => string(39) "Lily Beach Resort & Spa - All Inclusive" ["city"] => string(11) "Huvahendhoo" ["country"] => string(8) "Maldives" ["image"] => string(14) "41480_Main.jpg" ["address"] => string(0) "" ["wifi"] => NULL ["atoll"] => string(15) "South Ari Atoll" ["type"] => string(6) "Resort" ["stars"] => string(1) "5" ["room_id"] => NULL ["room_type"] => NULL ["description"] => NULL ["availability"] => NULL ["rates"] => NULL ["breakfast"] => NULL
    } [4] => array(17) {
        ["id"] => NULL ["hotel_id"] => NULL ["name"] => string(26) "Vakarufalhi Island Resort " ["city"] => string(11) "Vakarufalhi" ["country"] => string(8) "Maldives" ["image"] => string(14) "41483_Main.jpg" ["address"] => string(62) "ADh. Vakarufalhi, South Ari Atoll, Maldives Islands, Maldives " ["wifi"] => NULL ["atoll"] => string(15) "South Ari Atoll" ["type"] => string(6) "Resort" ["stars"] => string(1) "4" ["room_id"] => NULL ["room_type"] => NULL ["description"] => NULL ["availability"] => NULL ["rates"] => NULL ["breakfast"] => NULL
    } [5] => array(17) {
        ["id"] => NULL ["hotel_id"] => NULL ["name"] => string(29) "Banyan Tree Vabbinfaru Resort" ["city"] => string(10) "Vabbinfaru" ["country"] => string(8) "Maldives" ["image"] => string(14) "41485_Main.jpg" ["address"] => string(0) "" ["wifi"] => NULL ["atoll"] => string(15) "South Ari Atoll" ["type"] => string(6) "Resort" ["stars"] => string(1) "5" ["room_id"] => NULL ["room_type"] => NULL ["description"] => NULL ["availability"] => NULL ["rates"] => NULL ["breakfast"] => NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its much easier if you use the index `name` (hotel name) on this one and assign them to a new array. The first above answer wont be able to filter the same value because they are different (observe the index `id` of the first and second nested array, they wont match). Consider this example:

```
$original_values = array( array( 'id' => '1', 'hotel_id' => '1', 'name' => 'Vilamendhoo Island Resort & Spa', 'city' => 'Vilamendhoo', 'country' => 'Maldives', 'image' => '01.jpg', 'address' => '', 'wifi' => '1', 'atoll' => 'South Ari Atoll', 'type' => 'Resort', 'stars' => '4', 'room_id' => '1', 'room_type' => 'Garden view room - full board', 'description' => 'Limited Time Offer. Rate includes 20% discount!', 'availability' => 'only 4 rooms', 'rates' => '25', 'breakfast' => '1', ), array( 'id' => '2', 'hotel_id' => '1', 'name' => 'Vilamendhoo Island Resort & Spa', 'city' => 'Vilamendhoo', 'country' => 'Maldives', 'image' => '01.jpg', 'address' => '', 'wifi' => '1', 'atoll' => 'South Ari Atoll', 'type' => 'Resort', 'stars' => '4', 'room_id' => '1', 'room_type' => 'Garden view room - full board', 'description' => 'Limited Time Offer. Rate includes 20% discount!', 'availability' => 'only 4 rooms', 'rates' => '25', 'breakfast' => '1', ), array( 'id' => NULL, 'hotel_id' => NULL, 'name' => 'Kuredu Island Resort and Spa', 'city' => 'Kuredhdhu', 'country' => 'Maldives', 'image' => '12137_Main.jpg', 'address' => '', 'wifi' => NULL, 'atoll' => 'Lhaviyani Atoll', 'type' => 'Resort', 'stars' => '4', 'room_id' => NULL, 'room_type' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'availability' => NULL, 'rates' => NULL, 'breakfast' => NULL, ), array( 'id' => NULL, 'hotel_id' => NULL, 'name' => 'Lily Beach Resort & Spa - All Inclusive', 'city' => 'Huvahendhoo', 'country' => 'Maldives', 'image' => '41480_Main.jpg', 'address' => '', 'wifi' => NULL, 'atoll' => 'South Ari Atoll', 'type' => 'Resort', 'stars' => '5', 'room_id' => NULL, 'room_type' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'availability' => NULL, 'rates' => NULL, 'breakfast' => NULL, ), array( 'id' => NULL, 'hotel_id' => NULL, 'name' => 'Vakarufalhi Island Resort ', 'city' => 'Vakarufalhi', 'country' => 'Maldives', 'image' => '41483_Main.jpg', 'address' => 'ADh. Vakarufalhi, South Ari Atoll, Maldives Islands, Maldives ', 'wifi' => NULL, 'atoll' => 'South Ari Atoll', 'type' => 'Resort', 'stars' => '4', 'room_id' => NULL, 'room_type' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'availability' => NULL, 'rates' => NULL, 'breakfast' => NULL, ), array( 'id' => NULL, 'hotel_id' => NULL, 'name' => 'Banyan Tree Vabbinfaru Resort', 'city' => 'Vabbinfaru', 'country' => 'Maldives', 'image' => '41485_Main.jpg', 'address' => '', 'wifi' => NULL, 'atoll' => 'South Ari Atoll', 'type' => 'Resort', 'stars' => '5', 'room_id' => NULL, 'room_type' => NULL, 'description' => NULL, 'availability' => NULL, 'rates' => NULL, 'breakfast' => NULL, ),);
$new_values = array();
foreach($original_values as $key => $value) {
    $new_values[$value['name']][] = $value;
}

// simple reindex
$new_values = array_values($new_values);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_values);
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mJYUF1)

Edit: Simple output

```
foreach($new_values as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $element) {
        foreach($element as $index => $value) {
            echo $index . ' => ' . $value . '<br/>';  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Kevinabelita.
I tried your code it is compleatly remove the second (duplicate) Item. but I want to keep its other data.
simply if one hotel is having different types of rooms then I want to stop hotel name repeating and display all the rooms type under relevent hotel name. 
is there a way to do this? 
thank you

Comment: @Yasitha oh okay, you did not mention it earlier though, wait il make some revision.

Comment: @Yasitha if i understand correctly? you really didn't mean to remove duplicates, if there are duplicates which share the same hotel, group them accordingly, is that correct? check the revision i made

Comment: yes thats what I want to do. your revision is working as I feel but I can't display it using foreach loop. so how can I make it display.
Thank You very much for your effort.

Comment: @Yasitha okay if you want to just echo check the edit

Answer (score 2):

I've found this snippet here on `stackoverflow` and it is really useful.

```
$input = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $input)));
```

Here is the link to the original post with brief explanation.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/946300/1121121